# How to get literal SQL from ForeignKeyConstraints and other objects?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a bunch of databases with tons of tables, and the charsets and collations are a holy mess. I want to standardize all tables to charset utf8mb4 und to get rid of any charset declarations on (VAR)CHAR columns. For that I'm trying to write a script that reflects a database, goes through all tables and columns, and prints out the proper "ALTER..." statements where appropriate.

Its pretty simple to just alter table and columns charsets, but for anything that is part of a (foreign) key, that key first has to be dropped and later recreated.

So I'm looking at the ForeignKeyConstraints and PrimaryKeys of a table but I can't figure out how to get from that to the actual "CREATE ..." SQL statement, such as would be emitted by the MetaData.create_all() method.

I tried to use sqlalchemy.engine.Compiled() and looked at the source code under sql/.. in the sqlalchemy package to see how create_all() does ist, but didn't understand much. Below is a skeleton of my code so far. I don't want SQLQAlchemy to actually do the alterations, just to generate the SQL for me to review and then feed into mysql.

```
def fix_db(db_name):

    engine = create_engine(f'mysql://readonly@localhost/{db_name}')

    md = MetaData()
    md.reflect(bind=engine)

    for t in md.sorted_tables:
        print(f"ALTER TABLE `{t.name}` CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4;")
        for con in t.constraints:
            print(f'/* {type(con).__name__} `{con.name}`*/')
        print(f"ALTER TABLE `{t.name}`")
        for c in t.columns:
            if not hasattr(c.type, 'charset'):
                continue
            print(f'/* {c} */')
            if c.type.charset is not None:
                print(f"  CHANGE COLUMN `{c.name}` `{c.name}` {c.type}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fix_db('test')
```

[EDIT]
Actually, by now I have found the DropConstraint and AddConstraint classes which seem to be doing exactly what I want, but I haven't been able to find any equivalent for Columns. The CHANGE COLUMN statement above removes not only the type, but also other things from the column, such as defaults.